# JavaScript: How can I check whether a file is cached?

Tags: javascript, browser, caching

My site loads a pretty large js file the first time a user visits, and I want to write something like "Loading .. for the first time" it the file isn't from cache.

Is this possible in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

in your js

```
var loadedMyJS = true
```

in your html

```
 <script >
 function loadingIndicator(){ 
   document.getElementById('loadingDiv').style.display=''; //to hideit will be 'none' 
 }
 if(typeof(loadedMyJS) == 'undefined'){
    loadingIndicator();
 }

 </script >
```

Comment: And at the end of the JS, the code to remove the loadingindicator.

Comment: I think this is the only way to go - as far as I know, there is no way to find out whether a resource is cached or not

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing today. It does not detect whether the file was loaded from cache, only that the code is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

What about including a dynamic timestamp at the end, and checking it afterwards?

```
var t=<?php echo time(); ?>;
```

At least i'd get an indication after the fact. Or would I mess up other caching mechanisms by updating the file?